# Is jQuery .live() more memory intensive?

Tags: memory-management, jquery

Is jQuery .live() more memory intensive than a simple .click() .hover() or .keyup()?

I imagine it would be but to what degree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you're trying to accomplish. Just about every case I came across where I used `live()` ended up being better solved by `delegate()` anyways. (they are similar, but have a key difference) `live()` delegates to the root of the entire DOM tree, and checks each and every event that you specify. Using `delegate()` allows you to specify a different root that watches for events, which ends up performing much more efficiently.

Answer (score 7):

I'd guess that it is less memory intensive, but more processor intensive because it only assigns *one* handler function per event/selector, but it needs to <s>run</s> test for a match against that selector for every event of that type that happens on the page to see if it matches.

In fact, though I haven't dug deep into how it works, I'd imagine that it would need to <s>run</s> test for a match against the selector for every element from the `e.target` on up to the `document` (or until it finds a match) to see if anything along the way matches the selector. Someone else can correct me if I'm mistaken.

That said, when you do `$('.someClass').click(function() {})`, it too only uses the one handler function. So if there are 100 elements with `.someClass`, they'll all share the same function, but jQuery does need to create a unique entry in `jQuery.cache` for each element that gets that handler, and as such needs to manage them as though they were separate.

The `.delegate()` method is a nice compromise between the two.

It behaves the same as `.live()`, except that you assign it to a local part of the page, so it only processes clicks in that section. Therefore it doesn't need to consider *every* event that takes place on the page. Rather just those that happen inside that container.

---

**EDIT:** Improved phrasing of what the selector engine is doing, with credit to [@Šime Vidas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/425275/sime-vidas).

Comment: @Josiah: I can type faster than I can read, or think, which gets me into trouble sometimes. ;o)

Comment: @patrick Yea, that's probably how it works. For every event that fires, for each element between `e.target` and `document` inclusive, if the element matches one of the "live" selectors, and the event type also matches, then run the associated handler. Note: the phrase "running the selector" means searching for elements that match the selector (like `$(selector)`). In this case, we are matching the elements against the selector (like `$(element).is(selector)`).

Comment: +1 - You would be right about `.live` events bubbling all the way up to document. Remember, you cannot `e.stopPropagation` on `.live` handlers but you *can* on `.delegate` handlers.

Comment: @karim79: Yeah, it definitely relies on bubbling. The only thing that I've thought about recently is that it would need to test against the selector for *every* item in the path from `e.target` to `document`. I had previously thought of `.live()` as running the selector once per event, but I don't think that's the case.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: You're right. It is better phrased as you did with "matching against the selector". I think it's worth an update. Thanks. :o)